# un-log a times series while using the package forecast

Tags: r, time-series

Hello I use the package forecast in order to do times-series prevision. **I would like to know how to un-log** a series on the final forecast plot. With the forecast package I don't know how to un-log my series. Here is an example:

```
library(forecast)
data <- AirPassengers
data <- log(data) #with this AirPassengers data not nessesary to LOG but with my private data it is...because of some high picks...
ARIMA <- arima(data, order = c(1, 0, 1), list(order = c(12,0, 12), period = 1)) #Just a fake ARIMA in this case... 
plot(forecast(ARIMA, h=24)) #but my question is how to get a forecast plot according to the none log AirPassenger data
```

[image]

*So the image is logged. I want to have the same ARIMA modell but witht the none loged data.*

Comment: the exponential function is the inverse of the log function.

Comment: @ndoogan That is true, but is not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but it seems to do what you want. Based on your fitted model `ARIMA`:

```
fc<-forecast(ARIMA,h=24)
fc$mean<-exp(fc$mean)
fc$upper<-exp(fc$upper)
fc$lower<-exp(fc$lower)
fc$x<-exp(fc$x)
```

Now plot it

```
plot(fc)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactely what I wanted. ;)

Comment: Note that log(E(y)) is not equal to E(log(y)) ie. your forecasts are slightly biased if you just use the above transformation.

Comment: @hemmo In the spirit of SO, could you provide a new, better answer for the OP? Alternatively, edit the one I posted. Also, can you provide an example of what you mean by log(exp(y)) != exp(log(y))? Is it a precision thing? Something deeper?

Comment: @ndoogan I added an answer regarding this.

Answer (score 11):

It is not necessary to use the hack proposed by @ndoogan. `forecast.Arima` has built-in facilities for undoing transformations. The following code will do what is required:

```
fc <- forecast(ARIMA, h=24, lambda=0)
```

Better still, build the transformation into the model itself:

```
ARIMA <- Arima(data, order=c(1,0,1), list(order=c(1,0,1),period=12)), lambda=0)
fc <- forecast(ARIMA, h=24)
```

Note that you need to use the `Arima` function from the `forecast` package to do this, not the `arima` function from the `stats` package.

@Hemmo is correct that this back-transformation will not give the mean of the forecast distribution, and so is not the optimal MSE forecast. However, it will give the median of the forecast distribution, and so will give the optimal MAE forecast.

Finally, the fake model used by @Swiss12000 makes little sense as the seasonal part has frequency 1, and so is confounded with the non-seasonal part. I think you probably meant the model I've used in the code above.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good answer here.  ARIMA forecast returns the prediction in the original scale - so what gets returned is a prediction in terms of log(Airlinepassengers) because that was what was passed into ARIMA.  The challenge is how to get the prediction of log(Airlinepassengers) back to Airlinepassengers.  I would have thought it as straightforward as exp(logAirlinepassengers) but I don't think that is correct as some of you point out.  I'm faced with this problem now - 2 years after this post.  If anyone has additional insight I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There will be an option to return the mean in v7 of the forecast package -- now on github.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with @ndoogan's answer is that logarithm is not a linear transformation. Which means that E[exp(y)] != exp(E[y]). [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) gives actually that E[exp(y)] >= exp(E[y]). Here's a simple demonstration:

```
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(1000)
mean(exp(x))
[1] 1.685356
exp(mean(x))
[1] 0.9884194
```

Here's a case concerning the prediction:

```
# Simulate AR(1) process
set.seed(1)
y<-10+arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.9),n=100)

# Fit on logarithmic scale
fit<-arima(log(y),c(1,0,0))

#Simulate one step ahead
set.seed(123)
y_101_log <- fit$coef[2]*(1-fit$coef[1]) + 
             fit$coef[1]*log(y[100]) + rnorm(n=1000,sd=sqrt(fit$sigma2))

y_101<-exp(y_101_log) #transform to natural scale

exp(mean(y_101_log)) # This is exp(E(log(y_101)))
[1] 5.86717          # Same as exp(predict(fit,n.ahead=1)$pred) 
                     # differs bit because simulation

mean(y_101)          # This is E(exp(log(y_101)))=E(y_101)
[1] 5.904633

# 95% Prediction intervals:

#Naive way:
pred<-predict(fit,n.ahead=1)
c(exp(pred$pred-1.96*pred$se),exp(pred$pred+1.96*pred$se))
pred$pred pred$pred 
 4.762880  7.268523 

# Correct ones:
quantile(y_101,probs=c(0.025,0.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
4.772363 7.329826
```

This also provides a solution to your problem in general sense:

1. Fit your model
2. Simulate multiple samples from that model (for example one step ahead predictions as above)
3. For each simulated sample, make the inverse transformation to get the values in original scale
4. From these simulated samples you can compute the expected value as a ordinary mean, or if you need confidence intervals, compute empirical quantiles.